# Excel recalculation order - why dependent cell calculates before preceding cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a weird issue with Excel calculation order - dependent cell gets calculated before preceding cell with empty parameter value when setting range dirty. Is there any way to detect those "fake" calls? It is critical for me as I run some clever business logic in real world application and those "fake" calls break all logic. In addition those "fake" calls if registered with RTD don't bind it to the topic properly and thus don't notify topic disconnect.

Excel 2010/32bit latest all.

To illustrate problem I have created simple function:

```
Function Fnc(param2 As String) As String
    Fnc = Application.ThisCell.Address
    Debug.Print (Application.ThisCell.Address & " - " & param2)
End Function
```

And procedure:

```
Sub SetDirty()
    Range("B1:C1").Dirty
End Sub
```

And simple sheet:

$A$1    =fnc(A1)    =fnc(B1)

into cells A1, B1, C1.

And result obviously:

$A$1    $B$1    $C$1

If I recalculate (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) I get, as expected:

$B$1 - $A$1

$C$1 - $B$1

But, here goes the fun part. If I run SetDirty:

$C$1 -          <---- Where does this come from?

$B$1 - $A$1

$C$1 - $B$1

Thanks for any input. I would prefer a solution which solves this issue, not a workaround as it is already part of bunch of workarounds.

Comment: This page: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm, and others at the same site, should answer your question. It's author is also a regular on Satckoverflow.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are putting into which Excel cells - cau you pls take a screenshot or clarify your example?

Comment: @brettdj as I said in my post: $A$1 =fnc(A1) =fnc(B1) into cells A1, B1, C1 simple as that

Comment: @amas well you didn't say that. You said "$A$1 =fnc(A1) =fnc(B1)
In respective cells." with no mention of A1, B1 and C1. If you want our help then being clear on requests, and especially on follow-up if we ask for it is a much better path than being vague then incorrectly claiming you were clear initially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cells often get recalculated more than once: Excel starts with a recalculation sequence which is the previous calculation sequence plus LIFO (last in first out) for all modified cells.
This causes functions to be called and given uncalculated cells - the functions get called again later.
You can detect uncalculated cells in your UDF using IsEmpty 
See http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm for details on UDFs and detecting uncalculated cells
 and http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm for details of Excel's calculation sequence.
 
 BTW be careful with Range.Dirty - its a bit buggy

Comment: I am using C#, is it enough to check Value for null if cell HasFormula ?

Comment: I don't use C# (only VBA, VB6 and C++) so I cannot answer that: try some tests to see if Value is null detects empty cells. Why not just use IsEmpty http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value.aspx

Comment: IsEmpty is VBA function. Excel never pass null from formula. null can only be in two cases cell is empty or formula not calculated. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I agree with the caution about Range.Dirty - in this case the confusing extra call with a blank argument is caused by the Range.Dirty call. This has nothing to do with uncalculated cells.

Comment: You can use IsEmpty via C# Interop to detect if the Object retrieved from Range.Value is empty. See the reference I gave you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value.aspx#Y0

Comment: @Charles - Your calc write-up talks about uncalculated cells passed to a UDF with Range (or Variant) arguments. But in Arnas's example this happens even with a function taking a string argument. This is a surprise. Also that Full Recalc (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9) does not do this, but Range.Dirty does (as does some RTD cases apparently).

Comment: @Govert - I think it is correct for both cases. If you change string to Range/Variant/Object, you will be able to see empty/null value. While passing uncalculated cell with range might be "feature" of excel calculation, passing empty string while parameter is not calculated is certainly bug. As a workaround I changed parameter to object and check for null value to ignore fake call.

Comment: I just ran same test with Double parameter. same effect, just 0 instead of empty string.

Comment: I would have expected that converting an empty variant to a double gives zero, and converting an empty variant to a string gives an empty string. But I agree that in XLL speak it would be surprising if a type P/Q argument behaved like this, because I would expect the argument would be resolved as calculated before the function was called. A test case would be nteresting.

Comment: @Charles using XLL (ExcelDNA) I cannot reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @Arnas, Thanks - when I have some time I will do some XLL tests with different argument types, but I would expect it would only occur with type R being passed an uncalculated reference which would give xlRetUnCalc when you tried to Coerce it. Not sure how Govert handles this in XLDNA.